# KeyDown event can't use edited state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made `contentEditable` div to implement `ChatFooter` component like [this(Code Sandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/p56466rxvq).
but when i called `sendMessage` function via `onKeyDown` event, `message` value is still empty even i edited.
Weird thing is `message` value is working well on `onChange(actually onInput)` and when i called `sendMessage` directly with `onClick` event.

> Code Sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/p56466rxvq

P.S. it was same when i used `react-contenteditable` lib instead of mine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I saw in your code is that you are returning onKeyDown event from all keys except enter and shift. Also you are not setting the message property of state. You are sending empty message.